Grafana Service Fails When Using Port 443 Https
I want to run Grafana on Port 443 instead of 3000 in my EC2 server. I have modified grafana.ini file in /etc/grafana/ directory with this change:
# The http port  to use
http_port = 443

and then also executed the below command:
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/grafana-server

But when I see logs in /var/log/grafana/grafana.log I am getting the following errors:
logger=ngalert.state.manager t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.313820853Z level=info msg="Running in alternative execution of Error/NoData mode"
logger=infra.usagestats.collector t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.316189434Z level=info msg="registering usage stat providers" usageStatsProvidersLen=2
logger=server t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.316296026Z level=info msg="Writing PID file" path=/run/grafana/grafana-server.pid pid=42207
logger=provisioning.alerting t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.317006982Z level=info msg="starting to provision alerting"
logger=provisioning.alerting t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.317093762Z level=info msg="finished to provision alerting"
logger=grafanaStorageLogger t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.317452156Z level=info msg="Storage starting"
logger=secret.migration t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.319035527Z level=error msg="Server lock for secret migration already exists"
logger=http.server t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.321480465Z level=info msg="HTTP Server TLS settings" scheme=https MinTLSVersion=TLS1.2 configuredciphers=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
logger=server t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.321999389Z level=error msg="Stopped background service" service=*api.HTTPServer reason="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:443: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: permission denied"
logger=tracing t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.322172694Z level=info msg="Closing tracing"

How do I resolve this:

logger=server t=2024-07-31T09:38:32.321999389Z level=error msg="Stopped background service" service=*api.HTTPServer reason="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:443: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: permission denied"


The error depicts the port 443 already in use by some other process. You can check this doing netstat -anob or similar commands. Make sure you are configuring the grafana with a unique port which is unused.
